# Print class name from tensorflow object detection api

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

PLEASE NOTE: I have tried other solutions accross the web and didnt find the working result.
I am detecting objects from live feed using tensorflow object detection api and opencv. It is working fine and showing the boxes on the screen. Now i want to only print the detected object on the terminal.
I Have tried various solutions and couldnt find anything which worked. I am new to this.
Here's my code:

```
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
image_np = np.array(frame)

input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(
    np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)

num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
              for key, value in detections.items()}
detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

# detection_classes should be ints.
detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(
    np.int64)

label_id_offset = 1
image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()


viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image_np_with_detections,
    detections['detection_boxes'],
    detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
    detections['detection_scores'],
    category_index,
    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
    max_boxes_to_draw=5,
    min_score_thresh=.5,
    agnostic_mode=False)

cv2.imshow('object detection',  cv2.resize(
    image_np_with_detections, (800, 600)))
```

I tried using:

```
print(detections['detection_classes'])
```

But that just prints a set of values.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It is unclear what your objective is or what is the issue with the code you've posted.

Comment: I want to print the detected class

Answer (score 0):

```
print(category_index[detections['detection_classes'][np.argmax(detections['detection_scores'])]+1]['name'])
```

try using this ( here category_index is where all your labels are )

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

`category_index` is a dictionary with your label names. Index it with `detections['detection_classes']` to get the name of the categories. Something like this, but this won't work because I'm writing it directly on here without testing:

```
label_names = [i['name'] for i in category_index.items()]
label_names = np.array(label_names)

print(label_names[detections['detection_classes'].numpy()])
```